# Why do functions seem to be objects?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-2017

I am trying to learn JS/ES and am a bit confused about classes and objects.

The two code snippets below do exactly the same, but the last one is clearly using a class. But what is the first using? I thought a class became an object when executed?

I would have expected `clock` to be a function, but it can apparently be used as an object. Why is that?

And why would anyone ever want to use the class way, when the first is shorter to type?

```
var clock = {
  start() {
    setInterval(() => console.log(Date()), 1000) 
  }
}
clock.start()
```

and

```
class Clock {
  start() {
    setInterval(() => console.log(Date()), 1000)
  }
}
const c = new Clock
c.start()
```

Comment: now when we talk about “object” in daily scenarios, we usually mean the thing called “record” or “dictionary” in other languages, in js we call that “plain object”. So why `clock` is a plain object? Because you declare it that way. You declare `start` as a function, not `clock`.

Comment: Why ppl want to use class, because you can `var c1 = new Clock(), c2 = new Clock()` and save time.

Comment: @sinanspd Everything being an object is a good thing. It's the core design principal of "object oriented languages". And at this point javascript has evolved to fix the majority of its design issues.  (There still are a few, like problems with type coercion in comparisons).

Comment: Of note here, `clock` is not a function. It has a property `start` that is a function. But functions are objects, and that's a useful thing.

Comment: @GarrettMotzner That is extremely arguable. we have seen problems with OO design over and over again. Especially in concurrent settings. Whereas functional programming solves most of the issues OO design brings and more. Object oriented design is not mathematically sound

Comment: @sinanspd True, but you made it sound like this was a problem specific to javascript, and it is not.

Comment: @GarrettMotzner oh absolutely. My bad if I miscommunicated. Thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: When there wasn't "class" in JS we used to mimic classes as a function. The class function acting as the constructor, and then we would add properties and methods by inserting them to `function_name.prototype`. Whenever you use `new function_name ();` the function itself would run (acting as a constructor) and the new object would inherit the properties and methods you attached to the prototype. The thing about declaring "classes" as objects directly was about mimicking "static" classes. You can't use that to produce instances. Now there are elegant ways of doing the same thing under the hood

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Classes are templates for objects. They describe how a bunch of objects behave. In javascript, `new Clock()` is how you get a new *object* of the *class* `Clock`.

The object literal syntax (`{foo: 'bar'}`) is a shortcut to create a generic object. So the *class* of an object created that way is [`Object`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object). Also, creating an object that way doesn't give you a way to make `new` objects with the same behavior (which would mean in a sense they would be of the same class).

In some languages like C++ and Java, classes are fundamental  building blocks of the language. But in javascript, it's just a concept, and basically means (informally) any object that has the same specified behavior. More formally though it is an object that has the class prototype in its prototype chain. What are prototypes and prototype chains? Well, every* object (even those made with the object literal syntax) has a prototype as a hidden** property. When looking up a property in the object, if it isn't found in the object itself, it looks up the property in the prototype. And if that prototype object doesn't have that property, it goes "up the chain" and checks the prototype's prototype for the property, and keeps doing that as far as it can.

When you use the `class` syntax, you are setting properties on the prototype for every object that class creates. So in your example, you are assigning the function `start` to the prototype for every `Clock` object. But if you assign it to the object itself, then it doesn't use a prototype.

Interestingly, classes are also objects (they can have properties and methods).

For official documentation, see here:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/Object-oriented_JS
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/Object_prototypes

*: You can make an object without a prototype using `Object.create(null)`, but those are rare. The benefit of this is that you can't accidentally access properties of the prototype, because there are none.

**: You can sometimes access the prototype using the deprecated `__poto__` property. The preferred new way is `Object.getPrototypeOf(object)`

Here are some examples you can explore:

```js
const clockByLiteral = { start(){/* do something */} }
function startClock () { /* do something */}
class Clock {
  start() { /* do something */}
}

const clock1 = new Clock()
const clock2 = new Clock()

function getClassName(object){
  return object.constructor.name
}
console.log('"class" of clockByLiteral:', getClassName(clockByLiteral))
console.log('"class" of clockByLiteral.start:', getClassName(clockByLiteral.start))
console.log('"class" of startClock:', getClassName(startClock))
console.log('"class" of Clock class:', getClassName(Clock))
console.log('"class" of clock1:', getClassName(clock1))
console.log('"class" of clock2:', getClassName(clock2))
console.log('is the constructor of clock1 Clock?:', clock1.constructor === Clock, "(meaning that classes and constructors are the same objects, and are functions also")
console.log('is the prototype of clock1 Clock.prototype?:', Object.getPrototypeOf(clock1) === Clock.prototype)


console.log('is clock1 the same object as clock2?:', clock1 === clock2)
console.log('is clock1.start the same as clock2.start?:', clock1.start === clock2.start)
console.log('is clock1.start the same as Clock.prototype.start?:', clock1.start === Clock.prototype.start)

console.log('is clock1 an "instance" of Clock?:', clock1 instanceof Clock)
console.log('is clock1 an "instance" of Object?:', clock1 instanceof Object)
console.log('is clock1 an "instance" of Function?:', clock1 instanceof Function)
console.log('is Clock an "instance" of Function?:', Clock instanceof Function)
console.log('is startClock an "instance" of Function?:', Clock instanceof Function)
console.log('is startClock an "instance" of Object?:', Clock instanceof Object)
```